# MiniZinc's output command in Jupyter/Linux

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook, minizinc

The output command in MiniZinc under Jupyter/Linux is not executing.

When running:

```
    %%minizinc 
    var int: one_var;
    constraint one_var = 1;
    solve satisfy;
    output ["my var = \(2*one_var)\n"];
```

I'm getting

{'one_var': 1} which is the standard MiniZinc variables' output,

instead of

my var = 2

Thank
Ido

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered on one of the [MiniZinc GitHub repositories](https://github.com/MiniZinc/MiniZincIDE/issues/72):

> Hi Ido,
>
> I'm afraid that this is expected behaviour. When using the IPython
>   interface to MiniZinc, the MiniZinc variables are communicated
>   directly back to Python and the output item is ignored. This is
>   similar to setting the output modes for MiniZinc on the command-line.
>   You can use python to format the variables in any way you like. If you
>   want to do mathematical transformations on the variables you can even
>   add them to the model: `var int: my_var = 2*one_var;`
>
> One thing that could be interesting is to
>   add a feature to the python package to print the formatted output
>   statement. Note that this would only add output to the screen and the
>   print statement output would not be able to be used further on other
>   than as a string.
>
> Feel free to open a feature request for this feature in the
>   corresponding repository: https://github.com/MiniZinc/iminizinc. I'll
>   close this issue as it is not relevant to the MiniZincIDE